# EF Core - duplicate entry in table index when adding record to table with composite keys

Tags: entity-framework-core, duplicates, composite-key

I have a class with a composite key. When I try to save a record where a part of that key is contained in another record's key, I am getting an exception although the composite keys as a whole are unique.

Data type with navigation:

```
public class ProxyInfo
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0, TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string AccountID { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Key, Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string ProxyID { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProxyID))]
    public virtual UserInfo? Proxy { get; set; }
    // a few more properties
}
```

OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.Entity<ProxyInfo>()
    .HasKey(e => new { e.AccountID, e.ProxyID })
    .HasName("PK_ProxyInfo");

modelBuilder.Entity<ProxyInfo>()
    .HasOne(p => p.Proxy)
    .WithOne()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
// more code follows
}
```

Here's the relevant controller code:

```
[Route(Routes.Base + "[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProxyInfoApiController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DS2DbContext _context;

    public ProxyInfoApiController(DS2DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

[HttpPost("Add")]
[AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromBody] ProxyInfo proxyInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.ProxyInfo.Add(proxyInfo);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ServerGlobals.Logger?.Error($"ProxyInfoController.Add: Error '{e.Message}' occurred.");
        }
        return Ok(); // Created(proxyInfo.ID.ToString(), proxyInfo);
    }
}
```

The error message reads:

```
A row with a duplicate key cannot be inserted in the dbo.ProxyInfo
object with the unique IX_ProxyInfo_ProxyID-Index. The duplicate
key value is "X".
```

The complex key I tried to insert was {"B","X"}. The only other record in the ProxyInfo table has key {"A", "X"}; So there should be two different ProxyInfo records referencing the same UserInfo record.

**The problem seems to be that an index is being tried to be updated with a value it already contains. However, the indices of both records can be identical, as multiple ProxyInfos can reference the same UserInfo. So actually, no duplicate entry is created. It's just that a 2nd ProxyInfo record uses the same user as the 1st one.**

I just found out that the relevant index is created during initial migration with a unique:true attribute. The question is whether I can make EF Core skip updating the index when it already contains an index that it is trying to add again.

Comment: Remove Key annotations and ensure that `OnModelCreating` is called.

Comment: `Key` annotations are for single keys and somehow mess up the fluent configuration. As @Svyatosvav commented out, remove them and either use `PrimaryKey` annotation on class level, or the fluent API in `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: If you would have read my entire post, you would have noticed that I tried that. The problem seems to be that GetEdmModel is called before OnModelCreating, and error message about missing keys is created in modelBuilder.GetEdmModel. I am not EF Core 6, I cannot use Primary Key annotations.

Comment: We have read it, but there was no mention of OData in the original post. `GetEdmModel` is OData specific and has nothing to do with EF Core. EF Core needs `Key` annotation to be removed, period. Reusing the EF Core entity model for OData is your problem. Search for a way to configure composite key of OData entity using OData fluent APIs.

Comment: When I remove they Key annotation, I am getting an error message. I wrote that already. The problem manifests itself in an API controller, not an OData controller. I will find a solution, one way or the other, but I wanted to find out whether I made a mistake here, and which. Please keep your respectless and impolite tone to yourself. You are not helpful.

Comment: It has turned out the problem is a different one than what I believed it was in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was this statement:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProxyInfo>()
    .HasOne(p => p.Proxy)
    .WithOne()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

which should have been

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProxyInfo>()
    .HasOne(p => p.Proxy)
    .WithMany()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

What I also didn't know is that when I make changes like this one, I need to create and execute a migration. Once I did that, the index got changed into a non unique one.

I am only doing EF Core/Blazor for a year and I am dealing more with application development than with the framework around it, so this is all new to me and it took me a while to figure it out.